# How do I delete trailing objects drawn in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyautogui

My goal is to allow you to make a rectangle on your screen similar to using a rectangle or selection tool in paint. I've got it to mostly work but when you make a rectangle by holding left click and moving your mouse outward and then inward while still holding the button, it leaves behind rectangles that were previously drawn.

[Example image](https://files.catbox.moe/9yiq6d.png)

[Alternate example when I move my mouse everywhere really fast.](https://files.catbox.moe/6qi55t.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui

def draw_rect(event, canvas, pos):
    x, y = pos
    rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(
        x, y, event.x, event.y, outline="yellow", width=3, fill="blue"
    )


def draw_canvas(event, root, pos):
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="red")
    canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    root.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event: draw_rect(event, canvas, pos))
```

Comment: Are you aware that the canvas has a `delete` method? It's not clear what you're asking since this method is documented.

Comment: Yes I've tried adding canvas.delete(rectangle) but it immediately deletes it. Tried adding a queue or while loops and still couldn't get it to work. I want it to keep drawing the rectangle while you're holding down the button but delete the ones trailing behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of continuously drawing and deleting rectangles, you should draw a single rectangle and then modify its coordinates as you drag.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="black", width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def draw_drag(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    new_x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    new_y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords("current_rect")
    canvas.coords("current_rect", x0, y0, new_x, new_y)

def draw_stop(event):
    canvas.dtag("current_rect")

def draw_start(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x, y, fill="red", tags=("current_rect",))


canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", draw_start)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", draw_stop)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", draw_drag)

root.mainloop()
```